# Error loading tidyverse - Entry Point Not Found

Tags: r

I get the following error when trying to load the `tidyverse` package in R:

> The procedure entry point DATAPTR could not be located in the dynamic
>   link library

I am now using R 3.4, but the error has start after I have installed also the new release 3.5.

Any idea from where this error is coming from and what could I do to solve it?

Comment: Try to reinstall the tidyverse package

Comment: 3.5 is a "major release" so you have to reinstall any packages you used under 3.4.

Comment: Hello, I have reinstalled all packages in the 3.5 version but not in the normal install.packages() way. but as binary files and now all packages are loading fine.